# .Net support in bluemix buildpack

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ibm-cloud

The current [.NET Bluemix documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/dotnet/index.html) indicates that it supports beta8, but the doc also indicates RC1 is supported.  Does anyone know what is actually supported?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're asking a question about a product that you're working on and answer it yourself. This feels like spam

Comment: This question is not off-topic based on your explanation. This question and answer falls within the Stack Overflow guidelines as indicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score -1):

The ASP.NET 5 Buildpack in Bluemix actually supports both ASP.NET 5 Release Candidate 1 and beta8.  See this blog for more information and for details on migrating from beta8 to RC1:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/12/03/asp-net-5-buildpack-updates-for-rc1-support/